# Adding reference to a project allows to access references to referenced project

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I have a solution with 3 projects (.net core 2.0):

```
A
B => Reference A
C => Reference B
```

So the problem is that in C I can access A classes (that I think this is strange)!

This is behavior only with .net core.

Comment: Project reference? Package reference?

Comment: Project reference.

Comment: Ha, I only recently found this post. I have posted more or less the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46216375/preventing-net-core-nested-project-references